# Storing SQL Server queries in Excel VBA for joining

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, vba, adodb

I'm using ADODB to select data from SQL Server in my VBA code, and I'd like to join several queries.

Let's say I have two queries:

```
query1 = _
"select tblA.x,tblB.y from tblA inner join tblB on tblA.x=tblB.x"

query2 = _
"select tblA.x,tblA.abc from tblA inner join " & _
"(select max(tblA.x) as maxX from tblA group by x) qryA on tblA.x=qryA.maxX"
```

and I'm running the queries with:

```
Public sub getRecordsets(objConn as ADODB.Connection,rs1 as ADODB.Recordset,rs2 as ADODB.Recordset)

rs1.Open query1, objConn
rs2.Open query2, objConn

End Sub
```

I want to join these two queries in a 3rd recordset.  I know I can write one long SQL statement that joins both queries, but I'd like to leave them separate to make the code easier to maintain.

If I was using MS Access, I would create two stored queries `query1` and `query2`, then select from them as follows:

```
select y,abc from query1 inner join query2 on query1.x=query2.x
```

Is there a way that I can join the recordsets?  I don't have write access for creating UDFs or views in the SQL Server database; if I'm able to get write access, is that how I would have to do this?

Comment: Have you considered using `UNION ALL` and a single query? Why do you want a single recordset instead of the two individual ones?

Comment: @TimWilliams, I don't want a union of the rows from each query, I want to join them on their common key: `query1.x=query2.x`, so I can see which `y` values match which `abc` values.

Answer (score 0):

**If I were you I would do all the queries specially the ones with JOINS in them on SQL Server, as SQL Server can handle joins Faster and in a more efficient way. In this way you will only bring the records forward that you actually need rather then you bringing all the records and then filtering them on Access.**

Comment: What do you mean by doing the queries "on SQL Server"?  Write one big SQL statement and pass it to `recordset.open()`?  I'm trying to find a way to organize this as a set of subqueries that I can join, so that it will be easy to change or reuse these query components.

Answer (score 0):

You can't join recordsets as this is already a datastructure on the client side. That is what Muhammed Ali was trying to say, that you should execute the full query on the server. (as dealing around with recordsets is too late in the chain)

architecturing that in a way you'd like to have it is a different thing, although you'll ending up merging SQL statements, which is a parser/grammar stuff and IMHO more academic.

Actually - and we'll see if this entry survives long enough - I've seen quite a few questions from your side, which are interesting and smart but also somewhat extraordinary. Which forced me to comment, so you might ping me.

In general, I'd say netoffice could make your life a lot easier...